# Read Excel file from Memory in Django

Tags: django, pyexcel

I am trying to read an excel file from memory in django but keep getting the following error:

> NotImplementedError: formatting_info=True not yet implemented

Here's the code:

```
from pyexcel_xls import get_data


def processdocument(file):
    print("file", file)
    data = get_data(file)
    return 1
```

when I am reading the same file from the local storage it works perfectly

```
data = get_data(r"C:\Users\Rahul Sharma\Downloads\Sample PFEP (2).xlsx")
```

I had a workaound solution in mind i.e. to save the uploaded file temporary in django os and then pass its URL to the function.
Can I do that?

Comment: `xlrd` is good python package to work with `excel` files. you could save the uploaded files in any directory you wish, simply by using a function for `upload_to` option in the model related. then you know where it is, so give the `where` to the `xlrd`-based function to read the data you need.